# Printing both name and salary

Tags: java, binary-tree

So I am reading from a file(Consist of name and salary) and inserting into a tree. After that, I am doing a search method. It's working and printing true if the node exists. How do I print the actual name and salary just by searching by salary? Here is my search method:

```
    public boolean find(int salary) {
    Add current = root;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getSalary() == salary) {
            return true;
        } else if (current.getSalary() > salary) {
            current = current.getLeft();

        } else {
            current = current.getRight();
        }

     }
   return false;
}
```

And Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();

    bt.readfile();

    bt.print(bt.root);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Find method: return true if a node exits ,else return flase");

    System.out.println(bt.find(8900));`
```

Comment: please provide enough code, the Class BinaryTree for example

Comment: what are the instance variables of BinaryTree class ??

Comment: I have two class. Class binary tree under Add package.                    public class Add {

    int salary;
    String name;
    Add Left;
    Add right;

Comment: I also have Add root, and Add n under binary tree class.

Answer (score 0):

If `find()` returns a node, write a `toString()` method for the node such that the 
name is expressed.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public String toString(){

    return this.name + " " + this.salary;

}
```

**Why this works:**

When the `System.out.println()` calls on your node it will automatically call on the memory address. If you override this call with your custom method you can define what variables are printed out.

Comment: Jeffrey your approach is right but he still needs to provide the Class BinaryTree for final decision